# Problem in final render image with CYCLES!

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, image, path

Hi I' ve got this some problem during my last project in blender. I am using Cycles to render that scene, and somehow, the final image' s showing me this kinda box that seems like the path tracing shape, i don' t know how to remove that. I' d try remove, switching off the denoise, changing sampling, light paths, and more stuff. I'm gonna link the final image[image]
Someone of you could help me?
I will be so glad, cause i' ve a deadline, for this project.

Comment: are you using compositing?

Comment: No just the output render

Comment: Are you using an alpha build? Or the experimental feature set? This seems like the type of bug with the tiles you might see in an unofficial release

Comment: No i'm using an oficial release  the 2.8

Comment: Have you eliminated Z-fighting issues?

Comment: Does it appear with CPU-only rendering?

Comment: I don t no how to eliminated the z fighting, and i solved the problem, rendering just with the gpu but i need to rendering faster with both, how can i do? Thank you for helping me guys